# Couldn't able to compile the java program(Note: No Access to environment variable setup)

Tags: java, compiler-errors, environment-variables, javac, java-home

As I tried compiling the java program it shows as,

**'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

As all know that this is because of the not setting the environment variable. But the thing I don't have access to add/modify the system variables.

Is there any way to by-pass this to make it run. Please advise.

Screenshot1:- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lLBP.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfktG.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1: Set %PATH% in **user environment variable** instead of system.
- Option 2: Use **set path command on every new cmd** which you launch to
  run/compile java
- Option 3: Make .bat batch files having set path
  command to run/compile java **[recommended for you]**

How to make batch files(windows only) to run/compile simple java code?

1. Create new text file
2. Edit above file and add below contents to it: 
   `echo off
   cls
   set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
   javac SourceFileName.java
   java MainClassName
   pause`
3. Save file and rename it as `launch.bat`

Comment: Thanks .. As im new to java , It could be much helpful if u could post the sample code to do so..

Comment: This is not a Java specific problem.  It is a basic "how do I use the Windows command prompt" problem.  You probably need to read a tutorial on how environment variables work.

Comment: Arvind - sorry ... my comment was really addressed to the OP ... in response to his "show me how to do it because I am new to Java" ...

Answer (score 0):

Find out the path to `javac` on Windows using Windows Explorer `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin` and copy the path.

Add the path to environment variables like so:

Go to Control Panel, Environment Variables and Insert the address at the beginning of Path variable followed by a semicolon. i.e `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;` . 
Do not overwrite the existing path, just append the javac path to what you find there. Apply/save these changes and exit control panel.

Close and reopen your command prompt. Try to compile again.

Comment: You might have overlooked my question. Please note i dont have access to set the environmental variables. SUggest a way to bye pass using cmd prompt ..

Comment: @LazarThomas my bad, in that case, Arvind's solution above works :)

Answer (score 0):

THanks guys!!! Its worked..

set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin